# How to make scroll view in HTML using SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, responsive

I try to make the .mywork class is scrollable to the side, I alread tried to use overflow-x but still it didn't work. Instead, the result is like this:

[image]

The more .infoboxes classes I add, the more they overlap with each other instead of scrolling sideways. What went wrong and how to fix it? I am using SCSS/SASS.

this is the SCSS code:

```
.mywork {
    margin: 10% auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 95%;
}

.infobox {
    background-color: $seaLightYellow;
    border-radius: 30px;
    max-width: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;

    img {
        // border: 2px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    }

    a {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        background: none;

        &:hover {
            color: rgba (0, 81, 255);
        }
    }

    p {
        background: none;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .mywork {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .infobox {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="mywork">
        <div id="firstwork" class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_1.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink1.com/">New Link 1</a>
            <p>This is a new project I created. It's very exciting!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_2.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink2.com/">New Link 2</a>
            <p>This is another new project. I'm proud of my work!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_3.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink3.com/">New Link 3</a>
            <p>I've recently completed this project. It was a great learning experience.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_4.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink4.com/">New Link 4</a>
            <p>This project is my latest achievement. I'm thrilled with the results!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_5.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink5.com/">New Link 5</a>
            <p>I've just finished working on this project. It's been a challenging but rewarding experience.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_6.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink6.com/">New Link 6</a>
            <p>This project was a collaboration with talented individuals. I'm proud of what we've accomplished.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_7.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink7.com/">New Link 7</a>
            <p>Working on this project was a great learning opportunity. I've gained valuable skills.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_8.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink8.com/">New Link 8</a>
            <p>This project challenged me to think outside the box. I'm proud of the innovative solutions we came up with.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_9.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink9.com/">New Link 9</a>
            <p>Creating this project was a fulfilling experience. I'm grateful for the opportunity.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="infobox">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/new_image_10.jpg') }}" alt="No Internet" />

            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink10.com/">New Link 10</a>
            <p>I've recently launched this project. Check it out!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Children of a flex layout implicitly have `flex-shrink: 1` by default, which will attempt to shrink the main axis dimension of the children to fit the container. If you would rather this shrinking not happen, override `flex-shrink: 1` by applying `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex layout children:

```css
.mywork {
  margin: 10% auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 95%;
}

.infobox {
  background-color: $seaLightYellow;
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.infobox img {
  // border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}

.infobox a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: none;
}

.infobox a:hover {
  color: rgba (0, 81, 255);
}

.infobox p {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mywork {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .infobox {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mywork">
  <div id="firstwork" class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink1.com/">New Link 1</a>
    <p>This is a new project I created. It's very exciting!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink2.com/">New Link 2</a>
    <p>This is another new project. I'm proud of my work!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?0" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink3.com/">New Link 3</a>
    <p>I've recently completed this project. It was a great learning experience.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?1" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink4.com/">New Link 4</a>
    <p>This project is my latest achievement. I'm thrilled with the results!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?2" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink5.com/">New Link 5</a>
    <p>I've just finished working on this project. It's been a challenging but rewarding experience.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?3" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink6.com/">New Link 6</a>
    <p>This project was a collaboration with talented individuals. I'm proud of what we've accomplished.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?4" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink7.com/">New Link 7</a>
    <p>Working on this project was a great learning opportunity. I've gained valuable skills.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?5" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink8.com/">New Link 8</a>
    <p>This project challenged me to think outside the box. I'm proud of the innovative solutions we came up with.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?6" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink9.com/">New Link 9</a>
    <p>Creating this project was a fulfilling experience. I'm grateful for the opportunity.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?7" alt="No Internet" />

    <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://newlink10.com/">New Link 10</a>
    <p>I've recently launched this project. Check it out!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```